# Would Thanos include himself in his plan?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In *Avengers: Infinity War* Thanos wants to kill half the population of the universe, that's clear. And he wants to do that totally in random as well.

So, since he's also part of the universe population, does it mean that there is 50% chance he would die when he would finally snap his fingers after getting all the stones and his wish came true?

Comment: Downvote not mine .... the question is valid, if hard to answer with any source material.  However its been asked at least twice here already.

Comment: The downvote was mine, since *that* was the kind of title and question we get from spoiler paranoia. But I've since edited the question and reverted that downvote.

Comment: @iandotkelly thanks, I didn't go over all questions, and title wasn't clear enough to understand it's the same, lol. The spoiler paranoia the other mod talks about is totally real, I think 90% of the titles here are being edited. :)

Comment: Yeah, the fight against hot network questions here for big movies and tv-shows like game-of-thrones is ridiculous.  We end up with hundreds of strangely titled questions and a bunch of angry people who were spoiled by the original.

Comment: @iandotkelly I feel your pain! We should really let people opt out of certain sites in HNQ side bar, it will solve most of those problems. :-)